# Is there a way to have vectors outlined in a Vector Plot?

Tags: plotting

I am using the following code to make a 3D vector plot.

```
VectorPlot3D[{
  x (1 - x) - x*y,
  y (1 - y) + x*y - y*z,
  z (1 - z) + y*z},
 {x, 0, 1.2},
 {y, 0, 1.2},
 {z, 0, 1.2},
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"},
 VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
 VectorScale -> {0.05, 0.7, None}]
```

This makes a bunch of vectors, but the entire vector is colored. Is there a way I can use VectorStyle or another option to make each vector have a black outline, but have the inside of the area filled in with the appropriate color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Graphics` to define any shape for drawing the vectors. Something like this:

```
VectorPlot3D[{x (1 - x) - x*y, y (1 - y) + x*y - y*z, 
  z (1 - z) + y*z}, {x, 0, 1.2}, {y, 0, 1.2}, {z, 0, 1.2}, 
 Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
 VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow", VectorPoints -> 5, VectorScale -> {0.03, .7, None}, 
 VectorStyle -> Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Rectangle[{-2, -.2}, {0, .2}], 
    Polygon[{{0, .5}, {Sqrt[3], 0}, {0, -.5}}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly how I wanted the plot to look!